# Entity Framework 5.0 Dynamic Aggregate Field Expression

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, lambda, expression

I am working on a shared library function that takes an IQueryable and a field name and generates aggregate numbers for it (min, max, sum, avgerage).

I am using Entity Framework 5.0, .Net 4.5.1, and the Oracle 11g client software to connect to the database.

I'm generating the dynamic expression as follows.

```
ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");

Expression body = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, field);

Type fieldFuncType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(parameter.Type, body.Type);
LambdaExpression fieldLambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(fieldFuncType, body, parameter);

var typedQuery = (IQueryable<Entities.TSD_ASSET>)query;

Expression<Func<T, double?>> fieldExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, double?>>(Expression.Convert(fieldLambdaExpression.Body, typeof(double?)), fieldLambdaExpression.Parameters);
```

The variable fieldExpression appears to match a hard coded example expression of

```
Expression<Func<Entities.TSD_ASSET, double?>> hardCodedExample = (Entities.TSD_ASSET entity) => (double?)entity.assetHours;
```

when T is Entities.TSD_ASSET and the field name is "assetHours".

I am able to run an individual query aggregate call without issue using the following code line.

```
var temp2 = query.Max(fieldExpression);
```

But if I attempt to get all aggregates at the same time using the code below, I get the error "Unable to create a constant value of type 'Entities.TSD_ASSET'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.", and the query that is run is a select * from tsd_asset query, not a select extent1._max, extent2._min from dual cross join (select max() from tsd_asset) extent1 cross join (select min() from tsd_asset) extent2 type query that I see when using a hard coded example.

```
var brokenQuery = owner.DUAL.Select(x => new {
    _max = query.Max(fieldExpression),
    _min = query.Min(fieldExpression),
    _avg = query.Average(fieldExpression),
    _sum = query.Sum(fieldExpression)
});
var v5 = brokenQuery.ToList();
```

Note: owner.DUAL is an EF reference to the SYS.DUAL table.

using the hard coded expression from above against the query after casting to my example type works just fine.

```
var typedQuery = (IQueryable<Entities.TSD_ASSET>)query;
var workingQuery = owner.DUAL.Select(x => new {
    max = typedQuery.Max(hardCodedExample),
    min = typedQuery.Min(hardCodedExample),
    avg = typedQuery.Average(hardCodedExample),
    sum = typedQuery.Sum(hardCodedExample)
});
var v6 = workingQuery.ToList();
```

What am I missing in my dynamic method that is causing this type of behavior and error?

Comment: i'm not making this a real answer since it cheats around your issue. But use EF for what is good at CRUD and some moderate querying. Past that, you're just better off running an ad-hoc sql statement. I'm sure that you can make this work, but is it really making it easier? I'd rather have straight forward and long than short and complicated.

Comment: query is the IQueryable<T> passed to the function

Comment: I can do similar things with Sql Server without any errors. Maybe the conclusion should be that it's a bug in the Oracle SQL provider.

Comment: @Gert,  I was wondering that as well.  We're currently in the process of changing to EF 6 and Oracle's 12c Managed Client Driver, so I'll be able to check in a month or two when that is complete.